# Android kotlin loop to fetch data with OkHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am able to fetch data with the `okhttp.enqueue` method as defined below:

```
var url = "www.test.com?page="
var pageNumber = 1
var looper = true


// Should the below codes be placed into a `while(looper) { }` loop ??
val urlRequest = Request.Builder()
    .url(StringBuilder().append(url).append("$pageNumber").toString())
    .build()

httpClient.newCall(urlRequest).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        Log.i("test", "API call Failed: $call, $e")
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        val dataString = response.body?.string()  // parse the data into String
        val gsonResult = GsonBuilder().create()     // create a json object
        val finalData = gsonResult.fromJson(dataString, FinalData::class.java)
        if (finalData.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.i("test", "data is empty...  $pageNumber")   
            // When wrapping this code in a while loop, I would write `looper = false` here to break out             
        } else {  
            val a = finalData .value.size
            println("$a, $pageNumber")
        }
    }
})

pageNumber++
```

however, when I wrap this around a `while` loop to dynamically populate the `pageNumber` for dynamic fetching. I noticed that the code doesn't wait for the `onResponse` before going through the 2nd page onwards.

I understand that `OkHttp` is async and that's probably what's happening for the code to carry on execution without waiting for `onResponse`.

My question is, what is the correct method in handling this kind of looping to dynamically increase the `pageNumber` for http GET request?

**Note:** This is on Android. So it doesn't seem like they allow me to run such tasks on the MainUI thread.

Also, Is it possible to retrieve the `call` response **from** another function? `okhttp` doesn't seem to allow such an thing.

Comment: Most paginated APIs would indicate in the first response how many pages etc, you can use this to implement an optimised version that executes a single request followed by all follow up requests simultaneously.

Comment: sadly the API doesnt have any reponse on how many pages there are... Also, I should have been clearer that this is for Android. I'll update my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to just use execute instead of enqueue if you are happy with blocking imperative code.

```
package xxx

import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.Callback
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException

fun main() {
  val url = "www.test.com?page="
  var pageNumber = 1

  val httpClient = OkHttpClient()

  try {
    while (true) {
      val urlRequest = Request.Builder().url("$url$pageNumber").build()

      httpClient.newCall(urlRequest)
          .execute()
          .use { response ->

            val dataString = response.body?.string()  // parse the data into String
            val gsonResult = GsonBuilder().create()     // create a json object
            val finalData = gsonResult.fromJson(dataString, FinalData::class.java)
            if (finalData.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
              Log.i("test", "data is empty...  $pageNumber")
              // When wrapping this code in a while loop, I would write `looper = false` here to break out
            } else {
              val a = finalData.value.size
              println("$a, $pageNumber")
            }
          }

      pageNumber++
    }
  } catch (e: IOException) {
      Log.i("test", "API call Failed: $call, $e")
  }
}
```